# Error: wrap your Route components in a Routes component (change between versions 5 and 6 of react-router-dom)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm doing a course where version 5 of `react-router-dom` is used where there have been some pretty significant changes to `react-router-dom`.

When, launch the application, a white page appears in the browser, using devtools I get an error message: **Uncaught Error: A `<Route>` is only ever to be used as the child of `<Routes>` element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your Route in a Routes.**

Before I decided to write this post, I looked through various forums on how to solve this error, the two main solutions are as follows:

1. changing the version of `react-router-dom` to an older one (I do not want to use this method, I would like to solve the problem)
2. as the error  message suggests to wrap the `Route` in `Routes`. This is what I did. But it didn't work.

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Header from "./components/Layout/Header";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Routes, Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AddProject from "./components/Project/AddProject";
import { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/addProject" component={AddProject} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I changed the import I added `Routes` to it. I wrapped the `Route` in `Routes`. But it keeps getting the same error.

I don't know if I should remove the `Router`, but if I do it receives the error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing the `BrowserRouter` as `Routes`, and then importing the low-level `Router`. You are still missing the real `Routes` component wrapping the routes.

Fix the imports and then fix the route API/syntax.

Example:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router, // <-- this is the router
  Routes,                  // <-- this is the Routes
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import AddProject from "./components/Project/AddProject";
import { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/dashboard"
              element={<Dashboard />}  // <-- element prop takes ReactNode/JSX
            />
            <Route
              path="/addProject"
              element={<AddProject />} // <-- element prop takes ReactNode/JSX
            />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

You can also review the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) migration/upgrade guide for the other breaking changes from RRDv5 to RRDv6.

Answer (score 0):

`Route` syntax has also changed. Now it works like that: `<Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>} />` . You can view more in [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

Comment: The documentation link above returns a 404.  :(